# How can I block all mobile phones from accessing my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm in the process of building an ASP.Net/C# site on IIS 7.5 and I would like to block all mobile phones from accessing this website.

How can I block/deny access to this website (which uses Windows Authentication) from all types of mobile phones?  I'm building an internal application that I want only desktops with IE to access.  This is more of a security need than anything.

Ideally I would like to check to see if the user is accessing this website via mobile phone (or just approved browsers) first before any Windows challenge/response happens.

I've been looking to Google for pointers (with no luck) on this as well as looking at URL Rewrite options.  Since I'm relatively new to this aspect of Web Programming I'm at a bit of a loss on where to begin looking or if I'm even looking in the right places.  I'm not sure if I should just allow one approved browser through or block all mobile phones.

Comment: I shoudld note I'm a bit new to this aspect of web programming so I may have missed something obvious so forgive me in advance.  I've been googling for some pointers/leads on how to do this either by adding something to my aspx pages or even by using URL Rewrite.

Comment: Any reason you want to block mobile browsers? It sounds like a bad idea, and it could even backfire into mobile browsers pretending they're desktop, like IE pretended it was Mozilla, and KHTML claimed it was "like gecko".

Comment: I'm creating an internal application that I want only desktops to access.  It's more of a security need than anything.

Comment: Would it be easier to allow only 'approved' browsers as opposed to blocking all mobile phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only hope it to check for the User-Agent header property on the HTTP request, and deny content to those User-Agents coming from mobile phones.

Here's a list of user agents for mobile devices:
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

You'll have to use the `HttpResquest`.`UserAgent` property for that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: Might be a better strategy to pick the user agents you will allow, since the mobile ones are constantly changing but the browsers are fairly static, in comparison

Comment: @Crake unless it fires back into _yet_ more convolved user agents coming into existence. Remember "Mozilla/5.0 ... (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31"? Which browser is it actually? Hint: not Mozilla 5.0

Comment: I would hate to see mobile browsers pretending they're desktop browsers that are compatible to Mozilla 5 and their rendering core is similar to Gecko. This needs to die. User-agent based blocking needs to die.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to use an IIS module (like [URL Rewrite v2](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)) and do something like this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169853.aspx

Look at the request blocking feature.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking all mobile phones from accessing your website is not a practical or recommended approach. Mobile devices are a significant portion of internet traffic, and blocking them entirely would likely limit your website's reach and potentially frustrate legitimate users.

However, if you have a specific reason for wanting to limit mobile access to your website, here are a few options you can explore:

**User Agent Filtering:** Mobile devices typically send a User-Agent string with each request, indicating the device and browser being used. You can analyze these User-Agent strings and block requests from known mobile User-Agent strings. Keep in mind that User-Agent strings can be easily modified or spoofed, so this method is not foolproof.

**JavaScript Redirection:** You can use JavaScript to detect the user's device type and redirect mobile users to a separate page or display a message indicating that the website is not accessible on mobile devices. However, this approach relies on JavaScript execution, which can be disabled or bypassed by users.

**Responsive Design:** Instead of blocking mobile devices, consider implementing a responsive design for your website. Responsive design adapts the layout and content of your website to different screen sizes and devices, providing an optimal user experience regardless of the device being used.

**Mobile-Friendly Optimization:** Ensure that your website is mobile-friendly by optimizing its design, layout, and performance for mobile devices. This includes using responsive design techniques, optimizing images and other media for smaller screens, and ensuring fast page load times on mobile networks.

**Access Controls:** If you have a valid reason to restrict access to your website from specific mobile devices or IP addresses, you can implement access controls such as IP blocking or requiring user authentication. However, this approach requires careful consideration and should be implemented judiciously to avoid blocking legitimate users.

Remember, it's generally recommended to provide an inclusive and accessible experience for all users, regardless of the device they are using. Blocking mobile devices entirely is a drastic measure that should only be taken under exceptional circumstances. *

I blocked mobile users on my parenting blog and it significantly decreased my traffic.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).