# How to restrict access to some public websites

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to cloud computing. Sorry if this is a silly question. I have created a VM from azure portal. My requirement is not to allow the user using the VM to access public website. Can anyone help me how to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent arbitrary client apps from using anonymous web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5333368/608639), [How to block a specific App from accessing my website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39669951/608639), [How can I block all mobile phones from accessing my website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15932775/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a Network Security Group that was created when you created the VM. In there you can specify rules for inbound and outbound data traffic.

Find the NSG and add a rule that blocks all outbound traffic from the VM. You should still be able to connect to the VM, it just can't connect anywhere. You can also make the rule only block traffic bound to the internet if you still wish for it to have access to other machines in the same virtual network.

Network Security Groups documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is not to allow the user using the VM to access public
>   website.

According to your description, you just want user can't access **the public website**, as we know website common listen on 80 and 443, so we can add outbound rules to deny port 443, 80 and port 8080 to achieve this functionality.

I deny port 80, 443 and 8080, then my VM can't access https://google.com and http://google.com.
[image][image]

**Update**:[image][image]

Comment: Thanks. would you mind help me how to restrict accessing facebook and specific website. Thanks

Comment: @MukilDeepthi if you just want to block facebook, we can add outbound security rule,  select Advanced and type facebook public ip addresses in it. I will update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried this earlier but for somereason i keep getting invalid range when i type for eg: 66.220.144.0-66.220.159.255. is this not the right format?Thanks

Comment: @MukilDeepthi for now, NSG does not support IP range, just support 10.0.0.0/24 or xx.xx.xx.xx/xx

Comment: Ye sorry again. so what should be right entry in the source for blocking this facebook? will 10.0.0.0/24 will block facebook? sorry for the silly question :)

Comment: @MukilDeepthi  for example we can use 66.220.144.0/19 for 66.220.144.0-66.220.159.255

Comment: Sorry not working. Even i tried to block google.com as shown in your example but not able to block