# How i can block any android application to access my website?

Tags: android, security, web, apk, android-restrictions

Basically, this third-party application is using data from my website to fetch data and load into there application.

The scenario is this application has an internal login page on which end user insert my website credentials & this application fetch and load the data. 
I don't want to happen that.

1. I want to restrict this application also it is opening the entire
   page in `WebView` in another link.
2. Some of the requests are going with `X-Requested-With Header` what it
   means?

Can `CORS Headers`, `Domain Headers` or any security implementation we can try to mitigate this

Comment: what's the `UserAgent:` for the offending apps? maybe you can filter by that field

Comment: @lenik is it only restrict those or all android browsers. ?

Comment: You can't.  Any competent hacker will be able to easily get around any gimmick that tries to block based upon operating system of the source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent arbitrary client apps from using anonymous web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5333368/608639), [How to block a specific App from accessing my website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39669951/608639), [How can I block all mobile phones from accessing my website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15932775/608639), [How to restrict access to some public websites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44357371/608639), [How to limit web site access to USA or North America only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2111246/608639), etc.